# Unity 5.6: ram usage continues to grow

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, unity-game-engine

I have made this media player using Unity 5.6 video player and RawImage -component. If I keep it running for +40h straight it will run out of memory and crash. Error logs only indicates that memory is low.

Is there something I could do more memory-efficient in my code or somehow reduce memory consumption?

My test pc has i3 -processor and 4gb ram.

Thanks for advices :)

Player.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class Play : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization

    bool develop = true;
    bool web = false;

    //UI & Audio
    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    private VideoSource videoSource;

    private AudioSource audioSource;

    //Local
    private string path = "file://";
    private string folder = "C:/medias/";
    private WaitForSeconds waitTime;
    int arrLength;
    int i = 0;

    //Web (http)
    private string webpath = "http://";
    string uri = "www.rtcmagazine.com/files/images/5353/";

    string source;
    string str;
    WWW www;

    //Extensions to get
    string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".mp4", ".MP4", ".webm", ".WEBM", ".avi", ".AVI" };

    FileInfo[] info;
    DirectoryInfo dir;

    void Start()
    {

        //Add VideoPlayer to the GameObject
        videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();

        //Add AudioSource
        audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

        //Disable Play on Awake for both Video and Audio
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = true;
        audioSource.playOnAwake = true;

        if (web) {
            string[] fetchFilesCount = GetFiles (webpath+uri);
            int getLenght = fetchFilesCount.Length;
            info = new FileInfo[getLenght];
            int counter = 0;
            string[] filesFromWeb = GetFiles (webpath+uri);
            foreach (String file in filesFromWeb)
            {
                info [counter] = new FileInfo(webpath+uri+file);
                counter++;

                if (counter == filesFromWeb.Length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            info = new FileInfo[]{};
            dir = new DirectoryInfo(@folder);
            info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
        }
        arrLength = info.Length;

        Application.runInBackground = true;
        StartCoroutine(looper());
    }


    IEnumerator looper()
    {
        //Run forever
        while (true)
        {
            if (i == arrLength - 1)
            {
                if (web) {
                    int counter = 0;
                    string[] filesFromWeb = GetFiles (webpath+uri);
                    foreach (String file in filesFromWeb)
                    {
                        info [counter] = new FileInfo(webpath+uri+file);
                        counter++;

                        if (counter == filesFromWeb.Length) {
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    info = dir.GetFiles ().Where (f => extensions.Contains (f.Extension.ToLower ())).ToArray ();
                    arrLength = info.Length;
                }
                i = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
            //Debug.Log(info[i]);
            yield return StartCoroutine(medialogic());

            int dotIndex = info[i].ToString().LastIndexOf('.');

            //string lhs = index < 0 ? source : source.Substring(0,index),
            string searchDot = dotIndex < 0 ? "" : source.Substring(dotIndex+1);

            int dotPos = Array.IndexOf(extensions, "." + searchDot);
            if (dotPos > 5) {
                waitTime = new WaitForSeconds (0);
            } else {
                waitTime = new WaitForSeconds (7);
            }
            //Wait for 7 seconds 
            yield return waitTime;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator medialogic()
    {
        source = info[i].ToString();

        if (web) {
            if (develop) {
                www = new WWW (source);
            } else {
                www = new WWW (webpath+uri+source);
            }
        } else {
            if (develop) {
                str = path + source;
            } else {
                str = path + folder + source; 
            }
            www = new WWW (str);
        }

        int index = source.LastIndexOf('.');

        //string lhs = index < 0 ? source : source.Substring(0,index),
        string rhs = index < 0 ? "" : source.Substring(index+1);

        int pos = Array.IndexOf(extensions, "." + rhs);
        if (pos > -1 && pos < 6)
        {
            //Wait for download to finish
            yield return www;
            GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = www.texture;
        }
        else if (pos > 5)
        {
            //videos here
            videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
            videoPlayer.url = str;

            //Set Audio Output to AudioSource
            videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;

            //Assign the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played
            videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
            videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);

            //Set video To Play then prepare Audio to prevent Buffering
            videoPlayer.Prepare();

            while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            //Assign the Texture from Video to RawImage to be displayed
            GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = videoPlayer.texture;

            //Play Video
            videoPlayer.Play();

            //Play Sound
            audioSource.Play();

            //Set loop to true, hack for a freeze bug
            videoPlayer.isLooping = true;

            //Alternative way to check if video has ended
            videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;

            //Debug.Log ("Play started");

            while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
            {
                //Debug.Log ("playing");
                yield return null;
            }

            //Debug.Log("Done Playing Video");
        }
    }

    void EndReached(UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer videoPlayer) {
        //Debug.Log("End reached!");
        //Play Video
        videoPlayer.Stop();

        //Play Sound
        audioSource.Stop();
    }

    public static string[] GetFiles(string url)
    {
        string[] extensions2 = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".mp4", ".MP4", ".webm", ".WEBM", ".avi", ".AVI" };
        List<string> files = new List<string>(500);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

                Regex regex = new Regex("<a href=\".*\">(?<name>.*)</a>");
                MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(html);

                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                    {
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            string[] matchData = match.Groups[0].ToString().Split('\"');
                            foreach (string x in extensions2)
                            {
                                if (match.ToString().Contains(x))
                                {
                                    files.Add(matchData[1]);
                                }
                            }
                            //files.Add(matchData[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return files.ToArray();
    }

    public static string[] getFtpFolderItems(string ftpURL)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpURL);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        //You could add Credentials, if needed 
        //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "password");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        return reader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check out the **Unity3D Profiler**? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html

Comment: Would it be hard to detect this kind of thing, since the ram usage increases by so little over the time? I mean it took about 30 hours to consume 1 GB more of ram.

Comment: Not at all. Check the `GC` Behavior. Which objects get cleared, and which get every time instantiated again.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll start to experiment :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is clearly too long and complex to analyze toroughly and you should profile your application to know where most of the memory goes but I can give you a couple of hints.

Try to remove every single allocation from your loop.
I'm not sure whether there's a way to reuse the same  `WWW` or `WaitForSeconds` objects but you can try to cache and resure them instead of creating new ones every time.

Also, `foreach` loops allocate an `Enumerator` object. You can convert it to a regular `for` loop.

`GetFiles` is itself full of allocations. If your url doesn't change often, you can cache the result and reuse it.

```
info = dir.GetFiles ().Where (f => extensions.Contains (f.Extension.ToLower ())).ToArray ();
```

I would study this line very closely: `ToArray` allocates a new array copying all the elements in the enumerator. `GetFiles` again. The lambda expression itself needs an allocation. You can create a regular method and use it instead of the lambda expression. I'm not sure about `Where` but I think that allocates a new List too.
You might want to remove all of this.

There are also various string concatenations in your code and those allocate memory too. Consider using a `StringBuilder` instead.

Basically, caching is the key to reduce memory allocations in general.
Do it wherever possible, whenever needed.

Comment: You are incorrect about `foreach`, [when you foreach over an array the unity compiler turns it in to a for statement during compile so there is no itterator created at all](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/foreach-massively-slower-than-for-when-looping-through-vertices.235011/#post-1560056).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that, but he seems to be using foreach on a MatchCollection too and that instantiates a new object.